# How to attack on a web page to gain username and password?

Tags: authentication, passwords, attacks

In a situation where a web page is not using SSL and someone wants to attack to gain the username and password. How it can be done?

Given the situations:

- Passwords are not stored in plain text.
- Client side used languages : JavaScript, HTML, CSS
- Server languages: any
- One can try server side/client side attack.

Comment: Do you want to gain any username or password, or a specific user's credentials? HTML and CSS don't help you with an answer to this question. "Server languages: any" is the part that really needs to be fleshed out.

Comment: Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Server side scripting is SQL. The aim is to obtain any username and password. Please let me know if there is confusion still.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The lack of SSL opens the door for [MiTM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). So getting spyware on a router seems to be the benefit you'd get from the lack of SSL. Otherwise, I think the lack of SSL doesn't help you. You need to find an application attack, get malware in the browser or on the client computer, etc...

Comment: This answer doesn't really help with the question as stated.

Comment: Is there any possible way on server side?

Comment: For MITM attack, is it possible to spoof being outside the network? As per my detail, we should be in the same network of client. And for attack which tool is available . Thank you.

Comment: For MiTM attack you need to find a vulnerable router or use a network sniffer like wireshark. I'm not an expert in those and can't do more than point you in those directions.

Comment: Running a network sniffer on the server may be possible as well.

Comment: Thanks. it will be easy to use nmap for that purpose but I don't to know what to do access the user credentials.

Comment: I think nmap isn't what you want. It sends requests and monitors responses, not eavesdrops on connections. You want a [network sniffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer).